# One cinema display with two macs

Tags: cinema-display

Is there a way to connect two macs to a single cinema display? Of course I won't use them at the same time, but I want them to be connected to the display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At work, we refer to such devices as "switch boxes," though it appears that "video switch mini displayport" pulls up what you're looking for. The following appears to be what you're looking for:

[4-port DualView Mini DisplayPort KVMP Switch with Peripheral Sharing](http://www.iogear.com/product/GCS1924/)

Of course, you're just interested in sharing the display, but it does have a built-in USB hub, in case that's needed. It has a good desktop footprint, as well.

Comment: Thanks! I used them in the good old times of CRT monitors, and they are expensive as I remember them! :D